# Laravel 5.4 migrate error

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I made some migrations and when I tried to migrate I am getting an error.
I don't know where I made the mistake, I am new to Laravel migrations.

Below is the code of my migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFavouritesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('favourites', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('name_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('favourites', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');
            $table->foreign('name_id')->references('id')->on('names')->onDelete('CASCADE');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('favourites');
        Schema::table('favourites', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
            $table->dropForeign(['name_id']);
        });
    }
}
```

` and when I migrate, this is the error that I am getting:

```
 [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ugal`.`#sql-187c_52` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `favour
  ites` add constraint `favourites_name_id_foreign` foreign key (`name_id`) references `names` (`id`) on delete CASCADE)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ugal`.`#sql-187c_52` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Where is the mistake,and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should migrate table `names` before `favourites` table.